# lodash filter using forEach?

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

Having trouble filtering out some data from a deeply nested array of objects.

I need to loop through each day, then loop through each event and filter out all events that don't include an attendee with the email 'barry@gmail.com'.

```
'18 Sun': [
    {
        name: 'Event 01',
        attendees: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                email: 'john@gmail.com'
            },
            {
                name: 'Barry',
                email: 'barry@gmail.com'
            }
        ]
    }
],
'19 Mon':[
    {
        name: 'Event 02',
        attendees: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                email: 'john@gmail.com'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Event 03',
        attendees: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                email: 'john@gmail.com'
            },
            {
                name: 'Barry',
                email: 'barry@gmail.com'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

expectation after filtering (removed Event 02 since barry@gmail.com does not exist)

```
'18 Sun': [
    {
        name: 'Event 01',
        attendees: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                email: 'john@gmail.com'
            },
            {
                name: 'Barry',
                email: 'barry@gmail.com'
            }
        ]
    }
],
    '19 Mon':[
    {
        name: 'Event 03',
        attendees: [
            {
                name: 'John',
                email: 'john@gmail.com'
            },
            {
                name: 'Barry',
                email: 'barry@gmail.com'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried this snippet

```
_.forEach(globalEvents, d => {
        _.forEach(d, e => {
            _.filter(e.attendees, p => {
                return p.email === 'barry@gmail.com'
            })
        })
    })
```

but this just returns the entire, unfiltered array.  I would like to use lodash, but isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's works..

```
_.forEach(data, d => {
    _.remove(d, e => { 
        return _.some(e.attendees, {email: 'barry@gmail.com'}) != true;
    })
});
```